# Rstudio Import Dataset function produces different result to Preview

Tags: r, rstudio, readr

The following code was automatically generated in the RStudio "Import Dataset" function.  However, when I hit the Import button, I got different result.  The "Data Preview" section of Import Dataset recognised my login credential and returned 10yr data.  But when it was imported, it didn't recognise the login credential and returned 5yr data.  Any way to resolve this please so I can get the same result as the Preview when importing data?

```
library(readr)
ReportProcess4CSV <- 
read_csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=asc&columnYear=10&rounding=3&denominatorView=raw&t=MSFT", 
skip = 1)
View(ReportProcess4CSV)
```

Comment: I don't think this is anything to do with "Import Dataset" versus console. For once thing, the code generated by "Import Dataset" is simply copied to and run in the console. And I don't see anything in the code that relates to credentials. Perhaps your login expired between attempts?

Comment: When you say you "ran it in ID", do you mean that you saw results in the Data Preview window, and then you clicked "Import"? And when you say "in Console", you mean the RStudio console in the same session? Because clicking "Import" just copies the code preview to Console and runs it. So I am struggling to understand how there could be any difference.

Comment: That's correct, in "Data Preview" within Import Dataset, i can see the 10yr data which referenced my login credentials.  When I then hit the Import button, I only get 5yr data (without the credentials). apology for the confusion and many thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Well, that sounds like an interesting observation. Perhaps someone with good knowledge of RStudio internals can shed some light.